# X11VNC server service shuts down automatically after first connect ends

Tags: vnc

I have configured X11VNC server with SSL and server starts listening on the default port 5900 and I can connect to the server however, when the connection ends the server stops listening on the port as if the service stopped running!

I have been stuck around this for days and didn't know where to look exactly. when I start the application says that "Starting x11vnc seems to have failed.
Examine the logfile (Debugging -> show-logfile) for error messages."

On the log there doesn't seem to be errors or maybe there is but I couldn't see them! I'm not much familiar with linux servers yet. I'm attaching the log generated when starting the service

Logfile "log" current contents:

```
11/04/2014 19:41:34 passing arg to libvncserver: -passwd
11/04/2014 19:41:34 passing arg to libvncserver: -passwd
11/04/2014 19:41:34 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 25318
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Using X display :0
11/04/2014 19:41:34 rootwin: 0x284 reswin: 0x6000001 dpy: 0x19d4d30
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 ------------------ USEFUL INFORMATION ------------------
11/04/2014 19:41:34 X DAMAGE available on display, using it for polling hints.
11/04/2014 19:41:34   To disable this behavior use: '-noxdamage'
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34   Most compositing window managers like 'compiz' or 'beryl'
11/04/2014 19:41:34   cause X DAMAGE to fail, and so you may not see any screen
11/04/2014 19:41:34   updates via VNC.  Either disable 'compiz' (recommended) or
11/04/2014 19:41:34   supply the x11vnc '-noxdamage' command line option.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Wireframing: -wireframe mode is in effect for window moves.
11/04/2014 19:41:34   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
11/04/2014 19:41:34   errors, etc) it may be disabled:
11/04/2014 19:41:34    - use '-nowf' to disable wireframing completely.
11/04/2014 19:41:34    - use '-nowcr' to disable the Copy Rectangle after the
11/04/2014 19:41:34      moved window is released in the new position.
11/04/2014 19:41:34   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
11/04/2014 19:41:34   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to 
11/04/2014 19:41:34   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
11/04/2014 19:41:34   periodic repaints.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 XFIXES available on display, resetting cursor mode
11/04/2014 19:41:34   to: '-cursor most'.
11/04/2014 19:41:34   to disable this behavior use: '-cursor arrow'
11/04/2014 19:41:34   or '-noxfixes'.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 using XFIXES for cursor drawing.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 GrabServer control via XTEST.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Scroll Detection: -scrollcopyrect mode is in effect to
11/04/2014 19:41:34   use RECORD extension to try to detect scrolling windows
11/04/2014 19:41:34   (induced by either user keystroke or mouse input).
11/04/2014 19:41:34   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
11/04/2014 19:41:34   errors, etc) it may be disabled via: '-noscr'
11/04/2014 19:41:34   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
11/04/2014 19:41:34   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to 
11/04/2014 19:41:34   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
11/04/2014 19:41:34   periodic repaints.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 XKEYBOARD: number of keysyms per keycode 10 is greater
11/04/2014 19:41:34   than 4 and 108 keysyms are mapped above 4.
11/04/2014 19:41:34   Automatically switching to -xkb mode.
11/04/2014 19:41:34   If this makes the key mapping worse you can
11/04/2014 19:41:34   disable it with the "-noxkb" option.
11/04/2014 19:41:34   Also, remember "-remap DEAD" for accenting characters.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 X FBPM extension not supported.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 X display is capable of DPMS.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 --------------------------------------------------------
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Default visual ID: 0x21
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Read initial data from X display into framebuffer.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/7680
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Initializing SSL (server connect mode).
11/04/2014 19:41:34 RAND_file_name: /home/moh10ly/.rnd
11/04/2014 19:41:34 initialized PRNG with 1088 random bytes.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 created  512 bit temporary RSA key: 0.012s
11/04/2014 19:41:34 created 1024 bit temporary RSA key: 0.043s
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Using SSL Certificate:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
My certificate is here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

11/04/2014 19:41:34 using PEM /home/moh10ly/.vnc/certs/server.pem  0.000s
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 X display :0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Autoprobing TCP port 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Autoprobing selected TCP port 5900
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Autoprobing TCP6 port 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Autoprobing selected TCP6 port 5900
11/04/2014 19:41:34 openssl_port: listen on port/sock 5900/12
11/04/2014 19:41:34 openssl_port: listen on port/sock 5900/13 (ipv6)

The SSL VNC desktop is:  MyComputer:0
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Xinerama is present and active (e.g. multi-head).
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Xinerama: number of sub-screens: 1
11/04/2014 19:41:34 Xinerama: no blackouts needed (only one sub-screen)
11/04/2014 19:41:34 
11/04/2014 19:41:34 fb read rate: 498 MB/sec
11/04/2014 19:41:34 fast read: reset -wait  ms to: 10
11/04/2014 19:41:34 fast read: reset -defer ms to: 10
11/04/2014 19:41:34 The X server says there are 24 mouse buttons.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 screen setup finished.
11/04/2014 19:41:34 

The SSL VNC desktop is:  MyComputer:0

******************************************************************************
Have you tried the x11vnc '-ncache' VNC client-side pixel caching feature yet?

The scheme stores pixel data offscreen on the VNC viewer side for faster
retrieval.  It should work with any VNC viewer.  Try it by running:

    x11vnc -ncache 10 ...

One can also add -ncache_cr for smooth 'copyrect' window motion.
More info: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-client-caching
```

Comment: Not clear what I am asking? I'm asking why the service shuts down after I connect to VNC! That's not clear?

Answer (score 5):

From practically the very top of the man page:

> By default x11vnc will not allow the screen to be shared and it will
>   exit as soon as the client disconnects. See -shared and -forever below
>   to override these protections.

I also found this information by doing a search for 'x11vnc exits'.  The very first link had the answer.

Comment: I have just tried that but now the service gives another error "
Logfile "log" current contents:
>>> sending remote command: "qry=ping" via X11VNC_REMOTE X property.
error: could not connect to an x11vnc server at :0  (rc=1)

Comment: It seems there's a bug on the software! I have tried changing the name of the configuration file and made couple of copies then gave different name to each one of them with a different configuration. some without SSL configuration and some with. the one that worked was only the x11vnc file. I had another config file .x11vnc~ and others but none of them worked properly even though I could see server is listening on port 5900 and I can connect.